# The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install target/, Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have gone through a large amount of the threads with the same issue, but was unable to find a solution. I have tried the following:

- Manually partitioning the drive, creating an EFI volume at /boot/efi with 900mb size, and then creating the ext4 partition:
  [image]
- Disabling the 'connect to internet' option for the installer
- Disabling the 'allow third party drivers...'

Here is the final screen before the installation begins:
[image]

Nothing has worked so far. I am running the installation on a Microsoft Surfacebook, and prior to this it had Windows installed. I am not trying to dualboot.

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Note: The screenshot was taken from Kubuntu running off the live-usb

Comment: Have you set boot flag or ESP - efi system partition flag on your FAT32 partition?  Otherwise it is not the /target.

Comment: I don't think so. I didn't see an option to set any flags in the actual installer. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is that setting the Boot loader in the screenshot above to '/dev/nvme0n1p1' (which is the fat32 partition)?

Comment: It has to have the boot flag, does it? And you do not specify a partition but a drive or nvme0n1.  Installer automatically finds the ESP - efi system partition by the boot flag. Actually boot flag sets internally a very long partition type GUID that UEFI looks for.